# Is $[L^2(\Omega), H^2(\Omega)]_{\frac 1 2}=H^1(\Omega)$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Is the interpolated space of order $\frac 1 2$,

$$[L^2(\Omega), H^2(\Omega)]_{\frac 1 2}$$
equal to $H^1(\Omega)$?

I can't find any good examples of these interpolation ideas. Assume $\Omega$ is smooth.

Comment: Could you provide the definition of the interpolated space of order $1/2$? Did you mean `of the exponent`?

Comment: I am reading the book by Boyer, which just reference Lions, Magenes "Problemes aux limites non homogenes et applications. Vol 1." But [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation_space) may help

Comment: Yes, I checked that article, but the definition requires two compatible couples. Does your book imply that $X_0=X_1=L^2$?

Comment: The book doesn't make any reference to any other spaces, just the two I listed. I can't find anywhere with reference to this "order".

Comment: @TZakrevskiy FYI, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proposition 3.1 of Michael Taylor's PDE book (first volume) confirms that this is so for a compact manifold (which is what I was looking for).